# Configuring CORS for API Gateway in SAM/CloudFormation/Swagger

Tags: amazon-web-services, cors, aws-api-gateway

I followed the example from [here](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/tree/a71fc92754624d722f3216826df97a73403a4b7a/examples/2016-10-31/api_swagger_cors) which includes a swagger file for configuration of CORS + SAM. It seems like I still get CORS error unless I add CORS headers manually into each function:

```
callback(null, {
    statusCode: '200',
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'OPTIONS,GET,POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({message: "Hello world"})
});
```

Is this correct? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: if my answer has worked for you, please mark it as the "best answer" i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png

Answer (score 5):

All AWS docs suggest you need to specify those 3 headers in every API Gateway resource and return them in every function response that will support `CORS`, you can see they had to add those 3 headers to the 2 API Gateway endpoints defined in the example project's [swagger.yaml](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/a71fc92754624d722f3216826df97a73403a4b7a/examples/2016-10-31/api_swagger_cors/swagger.yaml#L50-L97) file.

The Github sample you mentioned is using what is called a `proxy resource` in `API Gateway`, which basically an `API Gatewaty` route that will match any request made to the api and trigger the proxy lambda function with the request's parth, method ... etc. You can learn more about how it works [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-set-up-simple-proxy.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-input-format).

Are you open to trying something like [serverless](https://serverless.com/framework/) which can help you better organize your lambda functions just like SAM does. It also [support CORS](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#enabling-cors).

Answer (score 1):

I know it is tedious task to add all these to your Swagger JSON for all the methods.

```
            "headers": {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        }
```

I have created a utility in Java which automatically adds these headers to your Swagger JSON. You can run it before importing it to API Gateway.

https://github.com/anandlalvb/SwaggerToAPIGateway

Answer (score 0):

We had similar problems when we are using * in Allow-Origin.

One Cannot use wildcard in Access-Control-Allow-Origin when credentials flag is true.

Replace

```
 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
```

With the your request url you are requesting from,

```
 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:8000',
```

or whatever your url is.

You also need to include port number as well in your return headers. It is also includes whether http or https as well.

If you want to automate is, get the referr url which you can whitelist and pass the protocol, host, port portion of the referrer.

Hope it helps.